# Convert tuple to series pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a tuple:

```
<class 'tuple'>
('JN997472', 'HM745930', 1)
```

And I need to convert it to a series so it matches the below format:

```
A                B
JN997472         HM745930        1
```

My attempt at this:

```
data = np.array(['JN997472', 'HM745930', 1])
ser = pd.Series(data)
ser.index = ['A','B','']
print(ser)

A    JN997472
B    HM745930
            1
dtype: object

ser.transpose()
A    JN997472
B    HM745930
            1
dtype: object
```

Comment: I feel there's a better solution to your problem. But `pd.Series([t[2]], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([t[:2]], names=['A', 'B']))` https://akuiper.com/console/TuRmhU-d1M92

Comment: Thanks dude, it's a very trivial problem but that works